# WPF DataTrigger restart animation when returning from previous state

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on a WPF application.  I have a ToggleButton that is supposed to glow green when it is selected and flash a red glow when there is an error in the model the button is associated with.  (It is an ObservableCollection<> ItemsControl).  The animation works fine when the DataTrigger executes, but I want the animation to resume if I select the button then deselect it.  In other words if there is an error associated with the buttons model (It is flashing red) and I select it (Now it is green) and then I deselect it then it should return to flashing red.  What is actually happening is once the button is deselected it just maintains its red state without flashing.  Here is my xaml.

```
<!-- This template is for the selection buttons on the left hand side of the application. -->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="SelectionControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Grid Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Margin="3" >
        <Rectangle x:Name="BaseLayer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" RadiusY="8" RadiusX="8" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Fill="{DynamicResource FutureBlueButtonGradient}"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="GlowLayer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="52.25" Width="52.25" RadiusY="6.5" RadiusX="6.5" Stroke="{x:Null}" StrokeThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="-1.125"/>
        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>

    <!-- Animation for blinking. -->
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="GlowLayer" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFFD0002"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="#3FFD0002"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="#FFFD0002"/>
            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </ControlTemplate.Resources>

    <!-- Style Triggers -->
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

        <!-- ERROR CONDITION TRIGGER: Flashes a selection button glowing red when HasTripOrError property is set to true. -->
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasTripOrError, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="GlowLayer" Value="{StaticResource SolidRedGlowBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Effect" TargetName="GlowLayer">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <BlurEffect/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="GlowLayer" Value="{StaticResource RadialGradientRedGlowBrush}"/>
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="ErrorGlowStoryBoard" Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="ErrorGlowStoryBoard"/>
            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        </DataTrigger>

        <!-- MOUSE OVER TRIGGER: Puts a white outline around the button and increases its brightness a little on mouse over. -->
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="GlowLayer" Value="#FFFDFFFE"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="BaseLayer" Value="{StaticResource FutureBlueButtonMouseOverGradient}"/>
        </Trigger>

        <!-- SELECTED TRIGGER: Makes the selected control glow green. -->
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Effect" TargetName="GlowLayer">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <BlurEffect/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="GlowLayer" Value="{StaticResource RadialGradientGreenGlowBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="GlowLayer" Value="{StaticResource SolidGreenGlowBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>

    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Here is the relevant code behind for the properties.  Please note that I have tried to raise the property responsible for the animation once it moves to the deselected state.

```
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _is_selected; }
        set
        {
            if( _is_selected != value )
            {
                _is_selected = value;
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("IsSelected");

                //We also need to raise the HasTripOrError property here to resume
                //The red glow animation if there is an error.
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("HasTripOrError");
            }
        }
    }

    public bool HasTripOrError
    {
        get { return _has_error; }
        set
        {
            if( value != _has_error)
            {
                _has_error = value;
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("HasTripOrError");
            }
        }
    }
```

How do I restart the animation once IsSelected transitions to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your `IsSelected` Property as :

```
 private bool _is_selected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _is_selected; }
        set
        {
            if (_is_selected != value)
            {
                _is_selected = value;
                UpdateProperty("IsSelected");

                //We also need to raise the HasTripOrError property here to resume
                //The red glow animation if there is an error.
                HasTripOrError = !HasTripOrError;
                HasTripOrError = !HasTripOrError;
            }
        }
    }
```

`HasTripOrError` is bound to a `DataTrigger`. So it will only execute when value of `HasTripOrError` will get changed.

```
 HasTripOrError = !HasTripOrError;
 HasTripOrError = !HasTripOrError;
```

> above code insures that `HasTripOrError` value will restore to
>   original value at last and If any `Binding` is associated that will
>   get reflected.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This works as intended.  I can't help but feel that I am not using it as intended.  Do you think there is something I should be using instead of a DataTrigger?

Comment: @ghost well the another solution depends on your scnario. what is the connection between IsSelected and HasTripOrError ? can't you use IsSelected in DataTrigger?